# Error: Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:29]

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to delete some rows from bigquery table using python code but I am getting the following error:

> Error: Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [1:29]

I am trying the following:

```
def delete_rows_of_failed_files(table_name, file_id, client):
    sql_query = "DELETE from {} where file_id = {}".format(table_name, file_id)
    try:
        query_job = client.query(sql_query)
        query_job.result()
    except BadRequest as err:
        error_message = 'Unable to delete data from table {} with file id = {}.  Error: {}'.format(
            table_name,
            file_id,
            err.message
        )
```

I have logged the table name to see if it is as expected or not: it's okay it's appearing as follows:

`BQproject_id.dataset_name.table_name` and the column name I want to evaluate its value and delete based on it is called `file_id` as appeared in `sql_query`, any idea what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have quoting issues. Try with:

```py
sql_query = "DELETE from `{}` where file_id = '{}'"
```

Comment: even when the passed file_id is string?

Comment: Yes, because Python will put the value 'file_id' into a string which will constitute the query, then pass that string-query to BQ. But at that point there won't be any quotes around your 'file_id'. And therefore BQ will try to put another meaning on it (a column name ? a function?) and not find anything. Hence the error.

Comment: yea understood, I will try it... and regarding the  `` around the table name what does it mean please?

Comment: The back quotes are usually put around the table identifiers (project.dataset.table). They are not mandatory though